# Division of two columns using group by

Tags: pandas, group-by

I want to compute division of 2 columns & create a column in the dataframe. Used the following code :

```
def divide_two_cols(df_sub):

  return df_sub['A'].sum() / float(df_sub['B'].sum())


Combined_Relevant["Ratio"]=Combined_Relevant.groupby(["Date",'Countries']).apply(divide_two_cols)
```

However , this gives me error. Can somebody help me rectify the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample:

```
Combined_Relevant = pd.DataFrame({
         'Date':['2019-01-01'] * 6,
         'Countries':list('aaabbb'),
         'A':[1,5,4,2,5,8],
         'B':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
})
```

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for Series with same size like original `Dataframe`:

```
g = Combined_Relevant.groupby(["Date",'Countries'])
Combined_Relevant["Ratio"] = g['A'].transform('sum') / g['B'].transform('sum')
print (Combined_Relevant)
         Date Countries  A  B     Ratio
0  2019-01-01         a  1  7  0.416667
1  2019-01-01         a  5  8  0.416667
2  2019-01-01         a  4  9  0.416667
3  2019-01-01         b  2  4  1.666667
4  2019-01-01         b  5  2  1.666667
5  2019-01-01         b  8  3  1.666667
```

Your solution working with `rename` and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
def divide_two_cols(df_sub):
  return df_sub['A'].sum() / float(df_sub['B'].sum())

s = Combined_Relevant.groupby(["Date",'Countries']).apply(divide_two_cols).rename('Ratio')
Combined_Relevant1=Combined_Relevant.join(s, on=['Date','Countries'])
print (Combined_Relevant1)
         Date Countries  A  B     Ratio
0  2019-01-01         a  1  7  0.416667
1  2019-01-01         a  5  8  0.416667
2  2019-01-01         a  4  9  0.416667
3  2019-01-01         b  2  4  1.666667
4  2019-01-01         b  5  2  1.666667
5  2019-01-01         b  8  3  1.666667
```